# Probability of an animal being eaten in a simulation from biology class

Tags: probability

I was working on a partner assignment in biology class where we each had two 10x10 grids with 100 spaces. Each square in the grid represents a portion of land. The simulation consisted of one person being assigned a prey species and another being assigned the predator species. For generation one each person would randomly mark 5 different spots on the 10x10 grid as representing the location of their assigned species (predator or prey). Then we would compare grids and if a square was marked on both of our grids then the predator ate that prey occupying the same square.

I was trying to come up with a way to predict how many prey would be eaten once the simulation was carried out given both the size of the predator and prey population not necessarily being the same. In other words if label x different squares randomly with the letter A in a 10x10 grid and in the same grid label y different squares randomly with the letter B allowing overlap between A and B, What is the expected number of squares containing both A and B? Note that two A's or two B's cannot occupy one square.

Comment: The number of overlapping squares will follow the hypergeometric distribution: (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). $N$ would be the total number of squares in the grid, and $K$ and $n$ correspond to $x$ and $y$ (or $y$ and $x$--it will be the same either way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to know "hypergeometric distribution" at all. Simply find the expected number of events in each square, which is either 1 or 0, and hence is equal to the probability of an event in that square. The total expected number of events is then simply the sum of expected number of events over all squares.